# Regular expression filter

Tags: sql, sql-server, wildcard

I have this regular expression in my sql query

```
DECLARE @RETURN_VALUE VARCHAR(MAX)  
IF @value LIKE '%[0-9]%[^A-Z]%[0-9]%'
BEGIN
    SET @RETURN_VALUE = NULL
END
```

I am not sure, but whenever I have this in my row 12 TEST then it gives me the value of 12, but if I have three digit number then it filters out the three digit numbers.How can I modify the regular expression to return me the three digits numbers too.

any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Maybe you can give some more examples of what you want to match and what you want to not match.

Comment: @driis: Looks like T-SQL to me,  but what version....

Comment: retagged to reflect the question's actual content.

Comment: Many would object to calling LIKE patterns a 'regular expression'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried ([0-9]*). I believe that this will capture every digit for you. However, I am not as strong at regex. When I ran this through [rubular](http://rubular.com/), it worked, though :) BTW, rubular is a great way to test out regular expressions

Comment: the OP's query doesn't use regular expressions (even though they described it as such)

Answer (score 4):

SQL doesn't have regular expressions: it has *SQL wildcard expressions*. They are much simpler than regular expressions and long predate regular expressions. For instance, there is no way to specify alternation (`a|b`) or repetition ( `a*`, `a+`, `a?`, `a{m,n}` ) such as you might find in a regular expression.

The 'like expression' that you have

```
LIKE '%[0-9]%[^A-Z]%[0-9]%'
```

will match any string containing the following pattern **anywhere in the string**

- zero or more of **any** character, followed by...
- a single decimal digit, followed by...
- zero or more of **any** character, followed by...
- a single character other than A–Z (whether it's case sensitive or not depends on the collating sequence in use), followed by...
- zero or of **any** character, followed by...
- a single decimal digit, followed by...
- zero or more of **any** character

One should note that the `%` is likely to match perhaps more than you might like.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily create a SQL CLR function and use this in your queries. Visual Studio has a project template for this and makes deploying the functions a snap.

[Here is more information](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163473.aspx) from Microsoft about how to create the function and how to use it (for boolean matches and for data extraction).

Answer (score 0):

First of all, note that this is not really a "regular expression", it's a SQL-specific form of  wildcard matching. You are very limited in what you can accomplish with SQL wildcards. As one example, you cannot "optionally" match a specific character or character set.

Your expression, as you've written it, will match any value that contains two digits with at least one non-letter character in between them, meaning it will match:

- 111
- 1^1
- 1?7
- 1AAAAAAAAAAA?AAAAAAAAA1
- -----------------------5-----------------3-------

And infinitely more items of a similar structure.

Oddly, one string that would *not* match this pattern is "12 TEST" because there is no character between the 1 and 2. The pattern also won't "give you" the value of 12 back because it's not a parsing expression, just a matching expression: it returns 1 (true) or 0 (false).

There is clearly something else going on in your application, possibly even an actual regular expression, but it has nothing to do with the SQL you've included here.